# why am I getting Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: javascript, html

I have another script with a google api, and no problems. Why would the eia gov api not work? I tried both ie and chrome. This is supposed to show the weekly fuel price for different regions of the country.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="generator" content="CoffeeCup HTML Editor (www.coffeecup.com)">
    <meta name="dcterms.created" content="Mon, 23 May 2016 14:38:22 GMT">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <title></title>

    <!--[if IE]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <script src="https//api.eia.gov/series/?api_key=00B011A9357DFF7E86E928531CFA26FD&series_id=PET.EMD_EPD2DXL0_PTE_SCA_DPG.W></script>

 </head>

 <body>


 <div id="California"></div>
 <div id="PET.EMD_EPD2DXL0_PTE_SCA_DPG.W"></div>



 </div>

 <script> 
 document.getElementById(PET.EMD_EPD2DXL0_PTE_SCA_DPG.W).innerHTML

</script>




  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: your URL is missing a colon after `https`

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a colon after "https" and a terminating quote in the src